# The driver is not executable for Chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I've tried setting the chromedriver permission and flagging it as executable. I set the PATH variable as well but still get this error. What other steps can I take to troubleshoot the issue? I'm running Jenkins with Git on an EC2 Linux instance.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Selenium TestNG ANT Build - Git/chromedriver.exe
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:534)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at WebDriver.TestNGScript.beforeTestsetUp(Unknown Source)
... Removed 22 stack frames
```

Comment: You are using a **Windows** `.exe` executable on a **Linux** machine.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 5):

The chromedriver.exe is a Windows executable, not for Linux. Download the Linux version and try again.

If you still get the error after downloading the Linux version of chromedriver, use terminal / bash to navigate to the directory containing the driver and type:

```
chmod +x chromedriver
```

Comment: I'll try that. Do I need to install a chrome browser as well and is that platform specific? The goal is to run selenium/testNG code from a Git repo using Ant/Jenkins on an EC2 instance. Are there any other dependencies that I need to implement?

Comment: There are a few dependencies, I used this gist a while back to get my Ubuntu instance running: https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3e8ab7e944d02fe872c3454d17af31a5

Comment: Pretty sure you need to install the browser you are testing against first, if you don't, the webdriver simply does not load, and as usual ,cryptic error messages.

Comment: I am also getting the same error. My Jenkins is running on Docker. I have logged in to bash of respective container and gave the permission but still getting the same error. Tried restarting the container as well.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/oCjUmcmqIz6V